# Carnot cycle with finite heat capacity

Tags: carnot-cycle

Suppose we perform a Carnot Cycle between 2 temperature baths $T_1$ and $T_2$ with $T_2>T_1$ and both having finite heat capacity $C$. What is the final equilibrium temperature?

I have a vague attempt and want to know if its correct:
$$dt_1=dq_1/C$$ and $$dt_2=-dq_2/C$$ where $dq_1$,$dq_2>0$
$$(dt_2/t_2)+(dt_1/t_1)=0$$
therefore on integrating initial and final temperatures we get $$T_f^2=T_1T_2$$.
So final temp=$$\sqrt{T_1T_2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using MathJax when typing formulas. Yes your reasoning is correct. Another way to get it directly is to notice that the entropy of the system is conserved by reversibility of the Carnot cycle. The total entropy is:
$$
S = C_1\ln T_1+C_2\ln T_2
$$
with $C_1,C_2$ the respective heat capacities of the baths. Thus the final temperature is the geometric mean of the initial temperatures, weighted by the respective heat capacities. If both capacities are equal, it is just the usual geometric mean.

Hope this helps.

Comment: By this reasoning of entropy conservation can we generalise the result for all reversible processes operating between T1 and T2 ?

Comment: Yes, still under the assumptions that your system is isolated. In fact, the maximal work you can extract from the initial inhomogeneity is given by the free energy, a related quantity.